# Android - How to do a callback function to get path image selected from gallery

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I need to call a function when the user select an image from gallery and get the path of the selected image. Following my code, activated by onclick:

```
protected Bitmap bitmap;
public void onclick(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);        
        startActivityForResult(i, STATUS);
}
```

I need a callback function because I want to store the selected image to the variable bitmap like following:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PATH_SELECTED_IMAGE);
```

How to do a callback function and get the path of selected image?

Comment: Did you read this? http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Yes, but I understand better with a pratical example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by overriding onActivityResult() method where you need to check for the requestcode you've given at the time of calling gallery intent.